# How can I retrieve a bucket which I have attached the wrong VPC access policy to?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have created a bucket for testing, which I have allowed access through the wrong condition through Terraform. Is it possible to regain access of the bucket? Let me illustrate with an example.

I have attached a policy to an S3 bucket, which looks like:

```sh
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "detached_bucket_policy" {
  bucket = module.s3_bucket_dummy_data_bucket.bucket_name

  policy = <<POLICY
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "SomeFoo",
    "Statement": [
        {
        "Sid": "Limiting-access",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Resource": ["${some_bucket_arn}",
                    "${some_bucket_arn}/*"],
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
            "aws:sourceVpce": "someEndpointThatDoesNotExist"
            }
        }
        }
    ]
    }

POLICY
}
```

Now because I have limited access to the bucket to only `someEndpointThatDoesNotExist` (which does not exist...) I now can no longer access the bucket via Terraform or the console.

Is there a way to reverse the damage?

Comment: Yes, log in as the root user of the account, that one can always access anything the account created, regardless of any given permissions. The root user should not be used for every day work, but exactly in these situation it *should* be used.

Comment: @luk2302 you should post this as an answer.

Comment: @luk2302 Please feel free to post this as an answer, and include more details if you like. I am happy to accept it = )